# Bootstrap change 15 px padding color for .container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to place an image in 15px padding to left and right on the .container class

Comment: The `.container` class already has 15px padding on the left and right. Share the code you've tried, and clarify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help I nested containers and it works great

Answer (score 1):

Add `background-color` to your container and place the `row` divs inside it. You will get the appearance as if the padding is grey.

```css
.container{
  background-color: grey;
  height:100px;
  }
  .inner-row{
 height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="inner-row"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this your expectation? Hope it's useful.

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
.yourImage {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<img src="http://www.webclasses.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/HTML.jpg" class="yourImage" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

give extra Class on container then overwrite the bootstrap css

eg:
**html**

```
<div class="container container-custom">
  ...
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container.container-custom
{
padding:0 5px;
}
```

Comment: .container.container-custom
{
padding:0 5px!important ; /*overwrite the css */
}

Comment: HI

thanks for the answer  here is a link to the page I want to fill the container padding with grey.

www.hitchesnmore.com/index123.php

Thanks

Comment: that's not possible to provide color on padding,, try to give a border on container.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a background image and place the container over it so I appears the 15px padding is the image or will the padding cover the background image also